# How can I increase the length of variable-length record beyond 32760?

Tags: mainframe, jcl, vsam

The maximum record-length for variable-length QSAM records is 32,760 bytes.

The current record-length of our file is OK for us, but in order to tackle some more info we have to expand this file which will have it's length beyond 32K (`LRECL` > 32760).

Splitting the record is not good option for us as it will impact our existing system.

I'm not sure whether using `SPANNED` records with VSAM here will solve this problem.

```
//DEFINE EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT  DD SYSOUT=A
//SYSIN     DD *

  DEFINE CLUSTER (NAME(dsname.K1719) INDEXED VOLUMES(xxxxxx) -
         TRACKS(1) KEYS(17 19) RECORDSIZE(40 110) SPANNED) -
         DATA (NAME(dsname.K1719.DATA)) INDEX (NAME(dsname.K1719.INDEX))
/*
//
```

Will this will solve our problem?

Comment: I presume maximum block length of 32k and not maximum file (or dataset) length of 32k; Also have you tried it to see what happens ???

Comment: @BruceMartin What I meant to say here - For VSAM file maximum length of CI is 32K. Does it means that VSAM file with SPANNED attribute can be use as an alternative to sequential file having LRECL > 32K?

Comment: It was foolish (as in wasteful of DASD to ever go beyone 27998 for a blocksize. Someone is paying for that mistake, and presumably not you. Yes, SPANNED in VSAM will allow you some pretty huge records. There is, of course, overhead in additional CPU, additional IO (EXCPS) and additional storage. All cost. Depending on how badly you use it, and how you are using it, maybe longer run-times. Hey, if you feel this is the easy way, and the client doesn't mind overpaying even more for your initial poor design, day-in-day-out, then go for it.

Comment: @BillWoodger Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: The initial "design" has dug you into a big whole. You can go sideways a bit, but you can't get out without fixing the design. The easiest thing to do is keep digging down, and hope that the client doesn't mind increasing costs and then discovering what they've been paying for. Obviously I'd not recommend that.

Comment: Can you add to your question confirmation of the details of the current file, how it is used (sequential access, for instance) and where it is used (Batch-only I hope)?

Comment: Also how many programs use the file?

Comment: I agree with Bill you need to look at the design of the file. If there are a lot of programs involved, you have just found out the hard way why it is often a good idea to have one "File Driver" program that accesses a complicated file i.e. Application-Program-->File-Driver-Program-->File.

Comment: @BruceMartin Exactly the approach I was going to suggest. Produce one (or more) logical records from more than one physical record (which don't even need to be on the same file). CALL in place of the IO, "record" define in WS (copybook) and stuff associated with that. No logic changes needed in the programs. Even with the SPANNED VSAM, all the programs would need to change (if QSAM originally) or be recompiled (if VSAM originally to have the new length. Can't break eggs without breaking eggs.

Comment: @BillWoodger Great mind think alike and Fools never differ; take your pick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Unix System Services files, you are not subject to the 32K limitation on LRECL.  There *are* downstream effects.

- If you are using COBOL to process the file you can use LINE
  SEQUENTIAL in the ORGANIZATION clause, but then you are limited to 1M
  LRECL.
- If you are using COBOL to process the file you can eschew COBOL I/O
  and use C `fopen()` and so forth to get around the 1M LRECL
  limitation mentioned above, but then you are adding something a bit
  foreign to an admittedly hypothetical COBOL application.  C would
  have no trouble with such files, I cannot speak to PL/I.
- Not all DFSMS and third-party utilities are completely conscious of Unix System Services
  files.
- JCL constructs for Unix System Services files have a relatively short
  learning curve, but there *is* a bit of learning required.
- Security for Unix System Services files may be off-putting to your
  Security Administrator(s).  You may find yourselves having to set up
  Access Control Lists via `setfacl` and other new concepts.

Comment: That's creative. Hopefully it'll spark OP into answering the questions asked of them.

Answer (score 1):

@cschneid answer is interesting.

With out knowing more about the file / application it is difficult to give specific answers. Following are idea's that may be useful.

You could:

- break the copybook up into several sub records
- add an extra byte to the key

so instead of having

```
<key><a record>
```

you would have

```
<key><sub-key-1><part-1-of-record>
<key><sub-key-2><part-2-of-record>
<key><sub-key-3><part-3-of-record>
 ...
```

---

If you have a single *File-Driver* program that interacts with the file,
you can hide the details of how the data is stored from your application. So you can have multiple physical records for each logical record and your application does nod need to know about it. You can also have multiple files if you need to as well

Remember you can add space at the end of the new copybook that does not need to be stored in the file. This comes in handy when you need to add fields to the file - can save recompiling lots of programs

---

Does the file hold logically different data (say *sales* and *orders* etc), does **every program** that accesses the file use the **whole** record ???

If so, you could add a request-type to the call of the *File-Driver-Program*:

```
   Call "FilePgm" using GET-ORDER  Order-Copybook
or 
   Call "FilePgm" using GET-SALES  Sales-Copybook 
or
   Call "FilePgm" using GET-EVERYTHING  Everything-Copybook
```

The advantage in having multiple call types/copybooks is if the Order-Copybook changes, programs only using the Sales-Copybook **do not** need to be recompiled and vice versa. This will make changing the file easier in the future.

---

Finally there is **Database Option !!!**, either a

- a full rewrite
- or the use of binary-blobs. These have a limit of 2gb on binary blobs

  With DB2 you can use **Compression** which can be useful. Large record often have high compression ratio's. The advantage with compression is not the space savings but reduced IO.